# Show that Icosahedral group does not have normal subgroup of order 5

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, polyhedra

Here is my work so far:

Let $G$ denote the group of orientation-preserving isometries of Icosahedron. I have shown that $G$ acts transitively on $G/G_s$ where $G_s$ is the isotropy group, namely $G_s=\{g
\in G:g(s)=s\}$ where $s$ could be a vertex, an edge or a face in the Icosahedron. Furthermore, I have shown that this implies that for any normal subgroup $N\subseteq G $, following holds: $$g(Nx)=Ng(x),\quad \forall \ x\in G/G_s, \ \forall g\in G,$$ where $Nx=\{n(x):n\in N\}$ is the orbit of $x$.

I know that $\{g\in G:\mbox{order}(g)=5\}$ can only be the group of rotations around a vertex by angles of $\frac{2\pi}{5},\frac{4\pi}{5},\frac{6\pi}{5},\frac{8\pi}{5},\mbox{ and }2\pi.$ I am planning to show that this group cannot be normal by showing the above equation breaks down. However, I cannot find exlicit example of $x\in G/G_s$.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a different strategy, but any subgroup of order $5$ is a Sylow $5$-subgroup, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems . As all such subgroups are conjugate, you just need to produce two to show that none can be normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Lagrange's theorem, we know that $|N|=5,|G|=60$ implies that $|G/N|=\frac{60}{5}=12=|V|$. The action of $G$ on $V$ is transitive. Hence $$\{g\in G:\mbox{order}(g)=5\}$$ is the group of rotations around a vertex $v\in V$ by angles of $\frac{2\pi}{5},\frac{4\pi}{5},\frac{6\pi}{5},\frac{8\pi}{5},2\pi.$ Let this group $G_v:=\{g\in G:g(v)=v\}$ be denoted by $N$. We show $N$ is not normal in $G.$ It is enough to find $g\in G$ such that the normality condition breaks down, i.e. $$g^{-1}Ng\neq N.$$ Let $g\in G$ be a rotation around the center of a face whose one vertex is $v\in V$ by angle of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Let $v_1,v_2\in V$ be the other two vertices of the face. Then, $g^{-1}ng(v)=g^{-1}v(v_1)\neq v,$ if $n(v_1)\neq v_1, \ n\in N.$ But $n(v)=v, \ \forall n\in N.$ It follows that $g^{-1}ng \notin N,$ if $n\neq id_G.$ Thus, $g^{-1}Ng\neq N.\Rightarrow N$ is not normal in $G.$